# Movie about aliens disguised as humans that turn out to be allergic to latex

Tags: story-identification, movie, alien-invasion

I saw this movie (or possibly mini-series) on TV (grandma had cable) in the mid to late eighties.  I was young, so I don't remember much.  Aliens were hiding as humans so it took a while to figure out what was going on.  There was a scene with a baby, sick in an incubator, but then his skin split open and it was a green alien baby.  I also remember a scene where there was a big balloon release because the aliens were allergic to latex, but then it seemed like the aliens went from being bad guys to good guys.

Comment: Makes me think of V

Comment: @Danny3414 : I got that vibe too (a really muddled memory of it there if it is that though) : accept they were never "_**hiding**_ as humans" in V : I don't remember anything about a latex allergy either?

Comment: I don't remember a latex allergy either. IIRC the Resistance tried to release a red dust bacteria but it didn't work in sunny climes (maybe!)

Comment: This is just plain funny, given the material of the usual alien costume/prosthetics in these shows and films.

Comment: @FuzzyBoots : I know, I did sort of wonder if that might be part of the years later muddle in memory from watching V (for example) as a child & remembering their human disguises being torn & such.

Comment: One of the plots later in the run of V (1984), IIRC: A human woman and a reptilian alien "visitor" disguised as a human fall in love and conceive a child. Concerns about the fetus arise when her lover is revealed to be an alien. Everyone is relieved when the child is born as an apparently normal human, but while it is in an incubator, its human skin splits open to reveal the reptilian alien within. I don't specifically recall anything about a latex allergy.

Answer (score 10):

Could this be a confused mash-up memory of V?

[V (1983 miniseries)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/V_(1983_miniseries))

> A race of aliens arrive on Earth in a fleet of 50 huge, saucer-shaped motherships, which hover over major cities across the world. They reveal themselves on the roof of the United Nations building in New York City, appearing human but requiring special glasses to protect their eyes and having a distinctive resonance to their voices. Referred to as the Visitors, they reach out in friendship, ostensibly seeking the help of humans to obtain chemicals and minerals needed to aid their ailing world, which is revealed to be a planet orbiting the star Sirius. In return, the Visitors promise to share their advanced technology with humanity. The governments of Earth accept the arrangement, and the Visitors, commanded by their leader John and his deputy Diana, begin to gain considerable influence with human authorities.

[V The Final Battle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/V_The_Final_Battle)

Part II of the second series ends with Robyn (a human character impregnated by an alien as an experiment) giving birth to surprise twins. The first baby appears mostly human, but unexpected baby number two crawls out of the womb shocking everyone with its reptilian appearance. [Birth scene on YouTube](https://youtu.be/cCWTgjPKaHE?t=163)

Near the end of the second series the human resistance used hundreds of Hot Air Balloons around the world to spread a virus/bacteria/toxin that was harmless to humans but deadly to the Visitors, to drive them off earth. They were able to spread it to the Visitor Mothership over LA and capture it. (Its been too long but I believe they also spread it to many/most of the Visitor ships too, so only a couple or a few would survive to the trip back to their home world.)

[image: Hot Air Balloons launching to spread the toxin]

[V (1984 TV series)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/V_(1984_TV_series))

I don't recall anything about an allergy to latex but that might simply be a confused memory of their latex disguises if you were young, otherwise the elements do fit & the time period it was aired is right.

They were green reptilian aliens disguised with latex skin as humans invading earth, they initially appeared to be benevolent & here to help us before it became an overt invasion & some of them did switch sides to join or help the human resistance in later episodes.

Google searches
[Images](https://www.google.com/search?rlz=1C1NHXL_enGB711GB711&biw=1280&bih=616&tbm=isch&sa=1&ei=6kBgXLq3Ddap1fAPjIWEgAg&q=v%2080%27s%20tv%20series&oq=v%2080%27s%20tv%20series&gs_l=img.12..0.6723.7168..8452...0.0..0.71.132.2......0....1..gws-wiz-img.......0i30.viGcdkqX7kc)
[Videos](https://www.google.com/search?q=v%2080%27s%20tv%20series&rlz=1C1NHXL_enGB711GB711&biw=1280&bih=616&tbm=vid&source=lnms&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj1mu64u7HgAhW-UBUIHeL0D98Q_AUICygC)

Comment: I was expecting Danny3414 to drop an answer, so as he was first in comments with V I wasn't going to, but he hasn't so I went ahead & posted it.

Comment: nah, you're ok. I've put a couple of answers in this week... don't wanna be a teacher's pet!